# Proc syntax in Haskell Arrows leads to severe performance penalty

Tags: haskell, arrows

Using `proc` notation for `Arrow` seems to kill performance in my project. Here is a toy example of the problem:

We define Coroutine newtype (mostly copying from [Generalizing Streams into Coroutines](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-01-08-streams-coroutines.md)) to represent Mealy machines (i.e. functions that carry some state) with instances of `Category` and `Arrow`, write `scan` wrapper function and `evalList` runner function for lists.

Then we have `sumArr` and `sumArr'` functions where the latter is the former called within `proc` block.

Compiling with `stack ghc -- --make test.hs -O2` using ghc-8.0.2 on OS X I get runtime of 0.087 secs for `sumArr` and 3.263 secs for `sumArr'` (with a heavy memory footprint).

I would like to know if this in fact caused by using `proc` and if I can do something to have normal runtime behaviour when using `proc` notation (writing arrow code without it is painful). Thank you.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category
import qualified Data.List as L

newtype Coroutine i o = Coroutine { runC :: i -> (o, Coroutine i o) }

instance Category Coroutine where
    id = Coroutine $ \i -> (i, id)

    cof . cog = Coroutine $ \i ->
        let (x, cog') = runC cog i
            (y, cof') = runC cof x
        in (y, cof' . cog')

instance Arrow Coroutine where
    arr f = Coroutine $ \i -> (f i, arr f)

    first co = Coroutine $ \(a,b) ->
        let (c, co') = runC co a in ((c,b), first co')

scan :: (o -> t -> o) -> o -> Coroutine t o
scan f = go where
    go i = Coroutine $ step i where
            step a b = let !a' = f a b in (a', go a')

evalList :: Coroutine a b -> [a] -> [b]
evalList a = L.map fst . L.drop 1 . L.scanl' (\(_, acc) v -> let !x = runC acc v in x) (undefined, a)

sumArr, sumArr' :: Coroutine Int Int
sumArr = scan (\acc x -> let !newAcc = acc + x in newAcc) 0
sumArr' = proc v -> do sumArr -< v

testData :: [Int]
testData = [1..1000000]

main = print $ L.last $ evalList sumArr' testData
```

Comment: Have you looked at the core to see how the two functions differ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, this is probably caused by `proc` notation. The desugaring is very low-level, introducing a lot of (needless) `arr`s and not taking advantage of `&&&` or `***` at all.

For example, last I checked, this:

```
mulA f g = proc x -> do
  a <- f -< x
  b <- g -< x
  returnA -< a * b
```

Is desugared to something like this:

```
mulA f g = arr dup
  >>> first f
  >>> arr swap
  >>> first g
  >>> arr mul
  where
    dup x = (x, x)
    swap (x, y) = (y, x)
    mul = uncurry (*)
```

When it could be just this:

```
mulA f g = f &&& g >>> arr mul
```

And this:

```
proc x -> do
  a <- f -< x
  b <- g -< a
  returnA -< b
```

Becomes something like this:

```
arr id
  >>> f
  >>> arr id
  >>> g
  >>> arr id
  >>> returnA
```

Instead of this:

```
f >>> g
```

Moreover I don’t think there are any GHC rewrite rules that take advantage of the arrow laws to help account for this.

Comment: So, what to do? Could we write our own rewrite rules?

Comment: @AJFarmar: That seems like the logical next step. I suspect that rewrite rules won’t be able to address all of the issues, though, so I’d also suggest filing a GHC ticket, or posting a message to the Glasgow Haskell Users or Haskell Cafe lists, to gauge interest in a proposal for an improved desugaring. I guess the main reason it’s unoptimised is that there are relatively few people using arrow notation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestions, I will ask this on the mailing list as well and post back here.

Answer (score 5):

I have found [arrowp-qq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrowp-qq) which wraps `proc` blocks inside quasiquotes and seems to produce better output than native desugarer. Performance is restored in the following version of our example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
...
import Control.Arrow.QuasiQuoter
...
sumArrQQ = [proc| x -> do sumArr -< x |]
```

One issue that I bumped into is that these quasiquotes don't play nicely with raw numbers inside the quotation.

```
sumArrQQ' = [proc| x -> do sumArr -< x + 2 |] -- gives an error

sumArrQQ'' = [proc| x -> do sumArr -< plus2 x |] -- compiles fine
    where plus2 = (+) 2
```